# Find the closest date per database row against a list of dates

Tags: javascript, sqlite, date, math

Say I have a bunch of numbers from the database (date timestamps):

```
date            count
------------------
1547015021      14
1547024080      2
```

and so on...

Then I have a range of timestamps that's generated based on a fixed period between them, like 1 day with 0 default count.

```
1546905600  - 0
1546992000  - 0
1547078400  - 0
...
```

How can I round the dates from the database to the nearest match from generated range?

Basically I want to come up with this result

```
1546905600  - 0
1546992000  - 14
1547078400  - 2
```

Comment: @Barmar I don't believe that this is a duplicate, rather that the title is not really indicative of the question. That is it appears that the result wanted is based upon the smallest difference between dates from the database against a list of other dates.

Comment: @MikeT He said that the list of other dates has a fixed period between them, so this is really equivalent to rounding to the nearest multiple of that period.

Comment: @Alex you may find this of use and perhaps familiar [How can I accumulate values from rows on a per closest date basis to a list of dates as a parameter according the parameter dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54121516/how-can-i-accumulate-values-from-rows-on-a-per-closest-date-basis-to-a-list-of-d/54121517#54121517)