# How can I accumulate values from rows on a per closest date basis to a list of dates as a parameter according the parameter dates?

Tags: sqlite

There is table that has a date and cnt column e.g.

> ```
> timestamp       cnt
> ------------------
> 1547015021      14
> 1547024080      2
> ```

This table can be created using :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS roundit_base;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS roundit_base (timestamp INTEGER, cnt INTEGER);
INSERT INTO roundit_base VALUES (1547015021,14),(1547024080,2);
```

The result should be the sum of the **cnt** column of rows that are the closest **timestamp** to a list of **supplied timestamps**, e.g. the supplied data could be

```
1546905600  - 0
1546992000  - 0
1547078400  - 0
...
```

The result should be along the lines of

```
1546905600  - 0
1546992000  - 14
1547078400  - 2
```

That is two columns:-

1. the **timestamp** from the list of **supplied timestamps**, that the respective rows from the database are closest to and
2. the sum of the **cnt** column those rows on a per **supplied timestamp**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the results are different from the expected results in that the calculations used places both **1547015021** and **1547024080** as being closest to the suplied timestamp of **1546992000**;

The following could be the basis of an SQLite based solution :-

```
WITH
-- The supplied list of timestamps
    v (cv,dflt) AS (
        VALUES (1546905600,0),(1546992000,0),(1547078400,0)
    ),
    -- Join the two sets calculating the difference
    cte1 AS (
        SELECT *, abs(cv - timestamp) AS diff FROM roundit_base INNER JOIN v
    ),

    -- Find the closest (smallest difference) for each timestamp
    cte2 AS (
        SELECT *, min(diff) FROM cte1 GROUP BY timestamp
    )
    -- For each compartive value sum the counts allocated/assigned (timestamps) to that 
    SELECT cv,
       CASE 
         WHEN 
                (SELECT sum(cnt) FROM cte2 WHERE cv = v.cv) IS NOT NULL 
         THEN
                (SELECT sum(cnt) FROM cte2 WHERE cv = v.cv)
         ELSE 0
         END AS cnt
    FROM v;
 ;
```

The above results in :-

[image]

Comment: @Alex that's good. Shame that someone couldn't see the original question as not a straight forward rounding, but that' SO for you.